# app-drawer no scrim on neon-animated-pages as content

Tags: polymer

When the `app-drawer` has the drawer open a gray scrim is put on the content

scrim
https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-drawer/app-drawer.html#L136

This works fine, but with a `neon-animated-pages` as content the scrim isn't applied. After some debugging
the reason seems to be the `position : absolute`.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/neon-animated-pages.html#L36

When replacing the `neon-animated-pages` with a retangular div with
`position : absolute`, this `div` is similar not covered with the scrim from the open `app-drawer`.

Anyone with ideas on how to get the `neon-animated-pages` to function together with the `app-drawer`?

---

Update, debugging more, by giving the `neon-animated-pages` a lower `z-index` the scrim is applied correct, so maybe a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by giving the `neon-animated-pages` a lower `z-index` than `app-drawer`, then scrim is applied correct and the rest of the application works ok.